# Cannot add item to listview using action bar

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

For the app that I am trying to make, the user will press the plus icon in the action bar and a custom alert dialog with an edit text pops up and asks the user to input text. After inputting the text and clicking "add" it should add an item to the listview, containing the text that the user inputted in the edittext. I used the Notepad example from the Android Dev Center and messed with the code in order to change it to my liking. However the issue is that when I press the "add" button, nothing changes. It doesn't add a list item at all.

**Notepadv2.java**

```
public class Notepadv2 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mNotesCursor;
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private Long mRowId;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        mRowId = null;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
            mRowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

            if (title != null) {
                mTitleText.setText(title);
            }

        }
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.INSERT_ID:
            createNote();
              break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote()
    {
           Context context = Notepadv2.this;
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alert.setTitle("Add note");
            alert.setMessage("Enter text here");

             // Set an EditText view to get user input   
              final EditText input = new EditText(this); 
              alert.setView(input);

              alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                      bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, input.getText().toString());
                      if (mRowId != null) {
                          bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
                      }

                      Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                      mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                      setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);

                  }

              });

              alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      /* User clicked Cancel so do some stuff */
                  }
              });

            alert.create();
            alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, mTitleText.getText().toString());
        if (mRowId != null) {
            bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
        }

        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        switch(requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
                mDbHelper.createNote(title);
                fillData();
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
                Long rowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                if (rowId != null) {
                    String editTitle = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
                    mDbHelper.updateNote(rowId, editTitle);
                }
                fillData();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**NotesDbAdapter.java**

```
public class NotesDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the note
     * @param body the body of the note
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createNote(String title) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @param body value to set note body to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

**notes_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/no_notes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**notes_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"/>
```

If anyone knows what code I can replace my code with to fix this issue, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about notes.notifyDataSetChanged(); ? It tells to listview that data has been changed.

Comment: I thought about that...but I have no idea where to implement it.

Comment: I fixed code. What is the value of constant int "RESULT_OK"? If the code still wont work try to replace "setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);" with "setResult(ACTIVITY_CREATE, mIntent);"

Comment: I tried that as well as adding `notes.notifyDataSetChanged();` but neither of them worked

Comment: If it helps at all, I checked the log cat when for when I press the "add" button and this is what I got http://pastebin.com/xspPtAQa

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Notepadv2 extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mNotesCursor;
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter notes;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        mRowId = null;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
            mRowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

            if (title != null) {
                mTitleText.setText(title);
            }

        }
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        mNotesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.INSERT_ID:
            createNote();
              break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote()
    {
           Context context = Notepadv2.this;
           AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alert.setTitle("Add note");
            alert.setMessage("Enter text here");

             // Set an EditText view to get user input   
              final EditText input = new EditText(this); 
              alert.setView(input);

              alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                      bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, input.getText().toString());
                      if (mRowId != null) {
                          bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
                      }

                      Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                      mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                      setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
                      notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }

              });

              alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                      /* User clicked Cancel so do some stuff */
                  }
              });

            alert.create();
            alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, mTitleText.getText().toString());
        if (mRowId != null) {
            bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
        }

        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        switch(requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                String title = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
                mDbHelper.createNote(title);
                fillData();
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
                Long rowId = extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
                if (rowId != null) {
                    String editTitle = extras.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
                    mDbHelper.updateNote(rowId, editTitle);
                }
                fillData();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i added `setResult(ACTIVITY_CREATE, mIntent);` and `notes.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the code, but I still get the same result. When I click "add", nothing happens. Anyone have any other ideas? Because I'm lost